# Base64 encode a javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, base64

I have large Javascript objects which I would like to encode to base-64 for AWS Kinesis`
It turns out that:

```
let objStr = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(obj), 'ascii');
new Buffer(objStr, 'base64').toString('ascii') !== objStr
```

I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible.

How can I base-64 encode JSON and safely decode it back to its original value?

Comment: Why would you expect them equal?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to do with `base-64` what `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` does on objects. How can I do that?

Comment: Would url-encoding work, too? The resultant string might be smaller than if it's base 64-encoded.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You misunderstood the `Buffer(str, [encoding])` constructor, the `encoding`  tells the constructor what encoding was used to create `str`, or what encoding the constructor should use to decode `str` into a byte array.

Basically the `Buffer` class represents byte streams, it's only when you convert it from/to strings that encoding comes into context.

You should instead use `buffer.toString("base64")` to get base-64 encoded of the buffer content.

```
let objJsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj);
let objJsonB64 = Buffer.from(objJsonStr).toString("base64");
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Regarding your example - it does not work on large JSONs. I've just checked that, the decode returns only partial of the original JSON.

Comment: How big is your JSON? I tried some large ones and it's working fine.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I probably selected only part of the encoded string.

Comment: `new Buffer()` is now deprecated, you should use `Buffer.from()` instead, see [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding)

Answer (score 160):

From String to Base-64

```
var obj = {a: 'a', b: 'b'};
var encoded = btoa(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

To decode back to actual

```
var actual = JSON.parse(atob(encoded))
```

For reference look here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: Have you tried this with non ASCII characters? atob and btoa are quite broken.

Comment: this won't work with not escaped charecters in JSON

Comment: @Bender can you please give an example?

Comment: @Kugel Any other solution available ?

Answer (score 16):

You can easily encode and decode from and to JSON/Base64 using a Buffer:

**JSON to Base64:**

```
function jsonToBase64(object) {
  const json = JSON.stringify(object);
  return Buffer.from(json).toString("base64");
}
```

**Base64 to JSON:**

```
function base64ToJson(base64String) {
  const json = Buffer.from(base64String, "base64").toString();
  return JSON.parse(json);
}
```

`atob()` and `btoa()` are outdated and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 2):

When converting object to base64 I was getting **out of latin range issues** and character invalid error.

I made it work in my project with the below line.

Include the `base64` and `utf8` node packages and access them like this:

```js
var bytes = base64.encode(utf8.encode(JSON.stringify(getOverviewComments())));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following offers some JavaScript for encode & decode of the Kinesis `data/Data` attributes.  For TypeScript, remove the comments:

```
const util = {
  decode: (str/*: string*/)/*: any*/ => JSON.parse(Buffer.from(str, 'base64').toString()),
  encode: (obj/*: any*/)/*: Buffer*/ => Buffer.from(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(obj)).toString('base64')),
}
```

Adding the event:

```
import {
  KinesisClient,
  PutRecordCommand,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-kinesis'
const kinesis = new KinesisClient({})
kinesis.send(new PutRecordCommand({
  StreamName,
  PartitionKey,
  Data: util.encode(obj),
}))
```

And receiving it in a Lambda:

```
import { KinesisStreamEvent } from 'aws-lambda'
const f = (event/*: KinesisStreamEvent*/) => {
  event.Records.forEach((event) => {
    const obj = util.decode(event.kinesis.data)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into almost the same problem
But the base64 code was returned from the server side and I could not convert it to json.
I also came across this question but it didn't help me
I decided to ask a question myself and got a complete answer
I will post the link here, maybe members will need it

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77893899/convert-base64-to-json-in-javascript)