# How to include a JSON encoded object as string in another object which will also be encoded in string

Tags: json, string

Suppose you have the following JSON object:

```
    {"name":"John Smith",
      "jsonData": "{\"comment\":\"He said \\\"It will work\\\", and we are waiting.\"}"
    }
```

The question is how to convert the above object to a string using say JavaScript JSON.stringify() and be able to save it in a text field in the DB and retrieve it later, parse it, and also part the inner encoded object `jsonData`?

The problem is faced in JavaScript and Java. For simplicity, I will reproduce the problem in JavaScript:

```
var jsonStr = `{"name":"John Smith",
                "jsonData": "{\\\"comment\\\":\\\"He said \\\"It will work\\\", and we are waiting.\\\"}"
               }`;
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
var comments = JSON.parse(obj.jsonData);
console.log(comments)
```

The above is failing with the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 21`

And, I couldn't figure out how to include a quoted string in the inner encoded JSON string `He said "It will work"`.

I want the solution in both Java and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered base64 encoding the JSON string?
Read more about base64 encoding objects here:
[Base64 encode a javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134200/base64-encode-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Yes thanks a lot... I think this is a better idea. I'll work on it. In the meantime could you please point me to the solution using escape characters?