# JavaScript object containing multiple Base64 image codes

Tags: javascript, object, webgl

**Project:**

Loading screen with Base64 image in Playcanvas (*WebGL*)

**What I try to do:**

Change the image when the Website is loaded with other language (*index.html?language=xy*)

**What I already have:**

I get the default image in my WebGL loading javascript.

```
 var logo = document.createElement('img');
    logo.src = 'here is my base64 code';
    splash.appendChild(logo);
    logo.onload = function() {
    splash.style.display = 'block';
    };
```

I thought it would be the best option to list all languages in an object, and invoke the object with the language that is currently selected.

**Why I can't figure it out myself:**

As I just started creating javascript projects, I need to lookup many thing, but when I search up my issue I get stuff like this [Base64 encode a javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134200/base64-encode-a-javascript-object)

Comment: What is exact issue here?

Comment: @Justinas I can't figure out how to list all codes in an object in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Define all the images in an object

   ```js
   const images = {
     'us': 'data:image/jpeg;base64,...',
     'nl': 'data:image/jpeg;base64,...',
     'fallback': 'data:image/jpeg;base64,...'
   }
   ```
2. [Parse the query paramters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript), use a fallback if not given

   ```js
   const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
   const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());

   let lanuageKey = params['language'];
   if (!images[lanuageKey]) {
       lanuageKey = 'fallback';
   }
   ```
3. Add the image with desired base64

   ```js
   var logo = document.createElement('img');
   logo.src = images[lanuageKey];
   document.body.appendChild(logo);
   ```

---

Putting this all together, will give something like the following snippet:
<sub>**Note 1**: Stack Snippets can't read the query params, so you'll need to try this locally</sub>
<sub>**Note 2**: Due to the 30k max chars, I had to remove the base64's</sub>

```js
const images = {
    'us': 'data:image/jpeg;base64...',
    'nl': 'data:image/jpeg;base64...',
    'fallback': 'data:image/jpeg;base64...'
}

const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());

let lanuageKey = params['language'];
if (!images[lanuageKey]) {
    lanuageKey = 'fallback';
}

var logo = document.createElement('img');
logo.src = images[lanuageKey];
document.body.appendChild(logo);
```