# convert base64 to json in javaScript

Tags: javascript, json, base64, decode, encode

For example, I have a `base64` code like this

```
const base64 = "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"
```

Now I want to convert this to `json`

I have tried to convert this base64 to object
But I don't know if it's true or not but still my problem is not solved because **I can't do anything with that `json`**

```
const base64 = "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"
```

> Convert to string using atob

```
let convertString = atob(base64);
```

> Convert string to ArrayBuffer

```
let arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(convertString.length);
let uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
for (let i = 0; i < convertString.length; i++) {
    uint8Array[i] = convertString.charCodeAt(i);
}
```

Now, using the `pako` library, it becomes an array that contains an object, but there is a space between all the characters, and this is very strange.

```
let inflatedData = pako.inflate(uint8Array, { to: 'string' });
console.log(inflatedData)
```

This is the image of the `inflatedData` console output

[image]

**A point that might help: the data that comes from the database is typed as varBinary(Max).**

Comment: Have you made an effort? Show what you've tried. Also, that base64 encoded string does not seem to result in any kind of human readable content.

Comment: Yes, I have done a number of things
I will definitely post the output right now
Thank you in advance

Comment: What you have there is JSON that has been gzipped and then base64 encoded, which is very strange.  gzip makes it smaller, and base64 makes it bigger.  So, you can use the `base64` module to extract the gzip, and the `gzip` module to extract the JSON.

Comment: @TimRoberts I edited the question and I think I did what you said, but the output does not work as you can see in the picture.

Comment: Looks like it's encoded oddly, those aren't just extra spaces. There's an extra `\u0` between every byte. You can test by running `echo "that string" | base64 --decode | gunzip - `. It'' show as (probably) intended in the terminal, but if you add a `| vim -`, it'll show with the extra chars. So you'll need to do something like `fixEncoding(gunzip(base64Decode(thatString)))`. Or fix whereever you're getting that data from.

Comment: @ZacAnger If I understand your meaning correctly, you say to test with this method to see if it works or not
"base64 string" | base64 --decode | gunzip

Comment: Are you sure the base 64 encoded string is an encoded json string?

Comment: @OmarHossamAhmed This code was given to me by someone who works on the database and she says that inside this is an array of objects

Comment: Well then an atob followed by a JSON.parse should be sufficient, but put it in a try/catch just in case.

Comment: Also one side note if base-64 is used for encryption that is not really secure. Just saying if that was the intention...

Comment: @OmarHossamAhmed Well, I did what you said
But it doesn't work at all
It can be tested on the console as well. If you don't mind, please do a test yourself. I will be grateful

Comment: @davoodbeheshti I'm saying that's how you can verify that what I said is correct, but that's not the whole solution. I figured out the encoding though, it's utf16le (or maybe ucs2). I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This string is a little funky. It's JSON in UTF16-LE, gzipped, then base64 encoded. In Node:

```js
const base64 = "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"

const zlib = require('zlib') // the builtin, not the old npm package
const buf = Buffer.from(base64, 'base64')
const res = zlib.gunzipSync(buf).toString('utf16le')

console.log(JSON.parse(res))
```

The result is an array of objects that look like test data.

---

Per the comments, here's how it could work in the browser. This assumes `pako`, which is mentioned in the question:

```js
import pako from 'pako'
const gzipped = atob(base64)

const toU = (d) =>
    new Uint8Array([...d]
        .map((c) => c.charCodeAt(0)))

const utf16 = pako.inflate(toU(gzipped), { to: 'string' })
const td = new TextDecoder('utf-16le')
const res = td.decode(toU(utf16))

console.log(JSON.parse(res))
```

There might be a more efficient way to do this, but it's very late, so I'm not able to see it right now.

Comment: I did not have the zlib package
I installed it now but it gives me this error
(Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zlib_bindings' in ....)
My project is Angular but I don't think it has anything to do with it

Comment: In Node, you don't need to install it, it's native. The `zlib` package on npm hasn't been upated in 12 years because there's a builtin module now. But that won't help if you're doing this client-side, you'd need to use `browserify-zlib` or something similar. I'll test and update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was fixed and it worked fine, thank you
This answer was approved and got a positive score, thank you very much